# How to use multidimensional array values in magento email template

Tags: event-observer, email, email-templates, transactional-mail, magento1.9.3.7

I am using Magento 1.9.3.7 version. I am triggering a mail from the observer with multidimensional array values. How I can get and use it in the mail template.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We should include a block with the template from a current theme inside the email template instead, just like we do for CMS pages. 
See below:

`{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='pathtotemplate/templatefilename.phtml' items=$items}}`

Then, you just need to sort out your data in phtml-file, see the following example:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
<p><?php echo $_item['name'] ?></p>
```

I referred [this](https://www.atwix.com/magento/pass-entities-collections/) link for the solution.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/120117)

Comment: @ManojDeswal Thanks for the comments. I changed the Answer.